# Vertical scroll is not working in my app in angular 10

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this template from angular 10. The problem is the scrollbar doesn´t work even if I add the css style on the main container `overflow: auto;`

The HTML and scss codes are as following, as you can see I include the overflow property to the main container "cont", but is not working:

Anyone can help with this? Thank you!

```css
.cont{
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form name="formEmpresa">
          <div class="container-background">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-building"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="J123456789" name="Rif" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <hr style="border: none">
                      <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-institution"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Razón Social" name="Razosoci" required ng-maxlength="150">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <hr style="border: none">
                      <label>Dirección fiscal</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Entre ..." name="Dir" ng-maxlength="200" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <hr style="border: none">
                      <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 20%;">
                          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color: white;"></i> <h5 style="color: white;"><strong>Añadir sucursal</strong></h5>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <hr style="border: none">
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #ffc107; color: white;">
                          <strong>Nueva surcursal</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                  <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-building"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Sucursal" name="sucursal" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <hr style="border: none">
                              <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                  <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" name="phone" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <hr style="border: none">
                              <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                  <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Código Postal" name="postal_code" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <hr style="border: none">
                              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Dirección" name="Dir" ng-maxlength="200" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think your scss file is not properly binded. Your html and css codes are works right

Comment: @AbdurrahmanY If i add on the div: <div class="cont" style="overflow: auto;"> doesn´t work anyway :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give some height to **.cont** class to add scroll to that div.

Comment: You are right! I have added height: 100% to the class, and it´s working now, thank you and problem solved!